# DDD - Should entities create entities?

Tags: domain-driven-design

In my domain I might have a entity called `User` that represents a person and `Tenant`, an entity that represents a business.

One might think that this is a administrative user, and as such, it should be able to register new users, which in terms of code would be translated to basically 3 forms:
-`adminUserInstance.CreateUser(newUserDTO);`
-`tenantInstance.CreateUser(newUserDTO)`
-`newUserInstace.SelfSave()`

Being `newUserInstace.SelfSave()` a necessity because of self-registration, does the other two make sense? Should i keep only the self registration and turn to a model of affiliation, where the same user can be part of multiple tenants?

In broader terms: should `Questions`/`Answers` be created by `Users` or self created and then tied to a given `User`? and on even broader terms: Should entities hold the knowledge to create other (not any-others) entities or the entities should be able to create themselves and have the "requester", for example, call a domain service that will bundle them up?

Answer (score 4):

> In broader terms: should Questions/Answers be created by Users or self created and then tied to a given User? and on even broader terms: Should entities hold the knowledge to create other (not any-others) entities or the entities should be able to create themselves and have the "requester", for example, call a domain service that will bundle them up?

[Udi Dahan](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/)'s technical guidance was that you should always get an entity, and use it to create the new entity.  "Customers don’t just appear out of thin air."

That said, creating aggregate root entities is *weird*; not "wrong", but it deviates from the usual patterns of dispatching commands to the aggregate you are going to modify.

Answer (score 2):

`Entities` can be created by `entities` but only inside the same `aggregate`. So, if an `aggregate` creates an `entity` then that `entity` is a nested `entity`; it cannot be referenced outside the `aggregate's` boundary. You put the creation of nested `entities` inside the `aggregate` because the `aggregate` needs to enforce some invariants and this is a decision to make when you design your `Aggregates`.

On the other hand, `aggregate roots` (`AR`) are created by the client code (an `Application` service in most cases) **but** the `AR` enforces it's own invariants! So, in PHP code this should look like this:

```
//somewhere in an Application service
function createUser($id, $username, $password) 
{
     $user  = new User(); //an AR should always be new-able, i.e. with not injected dependencies

     $user->registerNew($id, $username, $password); //here the invariants are enforced

     $this->userRepository->addOrSave($user);
}
```

> newUserInstace.SelfSave()

An `aggregate` does not "save" (persists) itself. That is the job of an `Application` service. Anyway, "save" does not seem to be from your ubiquitous language, you need a more proper name ("register"?).